# IComparable implemention for Segment class in Bentley-Ottmann algorithm

Tags: c#, intersection, segment

I'm trying to implement Bentley-Ottmann algorithm that is described [here](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0108/algorithm_0108.htm) in C#.
Particularly, I have a problem implementing IComparable<T> for **Segment** class in sweep line status structure. The segment class is listed below:

```
public class SweepLineSegment : IComparable<SweepLineSegment>
{
    public int Edge { get; set; }
    public PointF LeftmostVertexPoint { get; set; }
    public PointF RightmostVertexPoint { get; set; } 
    public SweepLineSegment Above { get; set; }
    public SweepLineSegment Below { get; set;} 

    public int CompareTo(SweepLineSegment other)
    {
        ?????
    }
}
```

I don't clearly understand how should I compare two segments when I add them to the sweep line status structure?

Comment: Is it possible to decouple your question from the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm? Doing so would make it beneficial to a larger audience.

Comment: According to Bentley-Ottmann algorithm the line segments that cross the sweep line are kept in the structure that is usually a balanced binary search tree (AVL-tree, RB-tree etc.). I try to implement simple generic BST for Segment class, but I need to know the correct way of comparison of Segment classes in order to implement it correctly. This way is closely connected to algorithm and is not clear for me.

Comment: So is your question simply, "How do I compare two custom objects (Segment in this case)?"

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to compare line segments to begin with?  There isn't any total ordering of tuples of four coordinates.

If you want the order in which the sides appear along the perimeter of the polygon, you should just keep track of the segment index.  I guess that's the `Edge` property?  Try `return Edge.CompareTo(other.Edge)`.

But I would suggest not implementing `IComparable` at all.  What do you need it for?